# how can I target filenames with 2 digits with the rename tool?

Tags: regular-expression, rename

I am trying rename files in a directory which have a 2 digit number - i.e. any and all numbers from 10 to 99.
I want to prepend a 0 so that for example 23 becomes 023, so that files like this

```
ep96Clone tool.mp4
```

rename to this

```
ep096Clone tool.mp4
```

I am using

```
rename -n 's/^ep([0-9]{2})([A-Za-z]*)/ep0$1$2/' *
```

but for some reason it is *also* matching filenames containing 3 digits, so rename is returning results like

```
ep101Blur_tool.mp4 renamed as ep0101Blur_tool.mp4
```

how can I restrict the substitution so that only files with 2 digits get renamed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the "*" in `[a-zA-Z]*`, which is matching no characters.
Replace it by `+` to match at least one alpha char.

Comment: that did it thanks, I cant see why exactly it worked though?

Comment: because `[a-zA-Z]*` can match absolutely nothing, it is as if this part of the pattern isnt even there, as there are no further rules in the pattern. So you were matching the first two digits of a 3 digit number, then nothing, and replacing them with a 0 and the 2 digits. The existing 3rd digit made the `[a-zA-Z]*` match with "*" meaning "none".

Comment: wow, so in other words `[a-zA-Z]*` is the same as `.*` ? because  in order for the backreference to capture the third digit (which it seemed to do) the `[a-zA-Z]*` must have matched to the digit?

Comment: no, `[a-zA-Z]*` didnt match the 3rd digit. Your entire pattern matched *before you got to the 3rd digit!*  The matcher saw the 3rd digit did NOT match a single  `[a-zA-Z]` char, so it tried to match no chars, and of course that matches anywhere, so it accepted the pattern, backing up to in front of the 3rd digit.